# Was the Seeker a devolved Xeelee?

Tags: stephen-baxter

In Stephen Baxter's short story *Cilia of Gold*, part of the Xeelee Sequence, the human characters encounter two important things - the remains of a crashed spacecraft on Mercury, whose hull material appears to violate the Pauli exclusion principle, and lifeforms that they speculate are the highly derived descendants of the ship's crew. One of these lifeforms, called a Seeker, lives as a parasite that infects other species and forces them to dig to the surface. The humans speculate that this Seeker could be the descendant of the ship's original crew, still following an instinctive drive to return to the surface for rescue.

The hull material matches the description of Xeelee Construction Material. No other species is known at this time to be able to produce the stuff.

My interpretation, then, is that the Seeker is the only time we've seen on the page an actual Xeelee, albeit one highly derived from the Baryonic Lords in their full glory. However, nobody else seems to mention this, ever. Am I misreading this?